# What happens if a user turns off Cookie within a GA session

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, data-layers

I am curious what happens if a user starts a GA session and let's say 1 minute later, the user turns off the Cookie, how is the information of that Session being recorded on GA?

I am curious if this would be the reason for the observation shown as the last record below:

[image]

As for the last record, I have 1 user but 0 session or 0 pageviews.

The first column is a user level customer dimension which indicates the user's Business Persona. The Persona information is passed from GTM via a data layer variable.

Any insight on the Cookie question as well as the abnormality observed above?

Thanks!
Yao

Comment: When do you set the value for this custom dimension? I'm assuming it is user scoped?

Comment: the customer dimension is with a user level scope. it was set up about three week prior to when the above report was pulled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user has already entered on your site, then the session has started, because page view hit was sent to GA. Hit can't be recalled. Turning off the Cookie can affect only on next hits.

What about events? Events without page view don't start session. Sessions will be 0, but user will be counted.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - it helps! Do you mind share light on how will a session duration be counted in the event a cookie is disabled in mid of a session?

Comment: @Yaolu I think, until last hit. For example, user opens page (page view hit), then clicks on some tracked button (event hit) and then turns off cookie. So, event hit is the last, session duration will from page view hit to event hit.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to make sense to me.